# open geolocation with cordova-plugin-geolocation in IONIC

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using IONIC V1 I know how to use the geolocation plugin (`cordova-plugin-geolocation` )  and it works. when I'm in the section of my map I get the notice that `"allow name_app to access to device location"`.

[image]

If my answer is `ALLOW`, the application assumes that the `gps` is activated.

but in the style of other apps I would like this to take me to the configuration of my device so that I mark the activation of the `gps` as in the image to be able to activate the `gps` in case it is not activated. (`ubicación= ubication` in my lenguage)

[image]

how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understand your problem correctly, you want open native `gps` setting if GPS is not enabled.

You can use any of below option:

**Using [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) plugin**

[isGpsLocationEnabled()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#isgpslocationenabled) function of diagnostic-plugin can help you to know if GPS is enabled or not.

Below is usage:

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isGpsLocationEnabled(function(enabled) {
        if (enabled) {
          //enabled 
        } else {
          // open location native location settings 
          cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
        }
      },
      function(error) {
        console.error("The following error occurred: " + error);
      });
```

**Using [request-location-accuracy](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy) plugin**

If request() function of location accuracy plugin gives you error callback. There you check if error code is ERROR_USER_DISAGREED, if true then use [switchToLocationSettings()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#switchtolocationsettings) of cordova-diagnostic-plugin to open native settings.

Below is usage:

```
function onRequestSuccess(success) {
  console.log("Successfully requested accuracy: " + success.message);
}
function onRequestFailure(error) {
  console.error("Accuracy request failed: error code=" + error.code + "; error message=" + error.message);
  if (error.code !== cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.ERROR_USER_DISAGREED) {
    if (window.confirm("Failed to automatically set Location Mode to 'High Accuracy'. Would you like to switch to the Location Settings page and do this manually?")) {
      // open location native location settings using diagnostic plugin
      cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
    }
  }
}
cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.request(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFailure, cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

Comment: Thank you! currently use cordova-plugin-geolocation, is it necessary to use the second code? or I still use the code I use for cordova-plugin-geolocation

Comment: @yavg you can keep using `cordova-plugin-geolocation` plugin as this is to get location from lat/long. Above solution is just to check if GPS is enabled or not, if not enabled then redirect user to native settings to enable GPS.

Comment: ahh I understand. the second code corresponds to the success and fallback that must go in the first piece of code.

Comment: thanks!, one last question. What is the order? first use the cordova-gelolocation-plugin plugin and then this? or vice versa?!

Comment: when I tap on "allow" I would like the code you told me to run.

Comment: Yes, order will be... first ask user for location permission. Once user tap allow after that check if GPS is enabled or not (my code). This will be flow. Enjoy!

Comment: how to install? cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic  this is all? thanks!

Comment: @yavg yes. Go to the root folder of your project and run this command `cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic`. You are done!

Comment: What's up friend. I'm here again I've tried this and although it works it's not the behavior I want. I want that If not enabled I want to point the user to turn on the location settings. this plugin activates it automatically. I would like you to have the behavior that you can see in the second image. I have another doubt, if the user does not accept to authorize the use of gps, if I navigate to another view and return to the map, he does not ask again if he wants to activate the gps. The solution is to uninstall the app and install it again. I appreciate your help

Comment: @yavg which solution did you try? First or second?

Comment: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy . "full android and Ios example"

Comment: Please use the first solution which will take you manually to the Native GPS settings screen. Regarding your second question, if user doesn't enable GPS and move to another screen and come back to map at that time pop-up not showing. For that you can use `$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){
  // Add your gps status code here
});` . Add my 1st solution code inside this event, then everytime user will come to map screen, it will first check if gps is enabled or not, if not enabled it will display pop-up (I have not implemented pop-up, in else part you can add it).

Comment: thanks! I explain, when I ask that if I want to allow the use of GPS, and I answer "deny", never even if you recharge your eyes, you ask again if you want to allow the use of GPS

Comment: hey, can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50804783/get-promise-of-the-result-of-activating-geolocation  this answer, not works for ios :(

Comment: can I in the else of `    if (window.confirm("Failed to automatically set Location Mode to 'High Accuracy'. Would you like to switch to the Location Settings page and do this manually?")) {
`  put an action if the user deny the use of geolocation?