# Get promise of the result of activating geolocation

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2, geolocation, ionic3

with this code:

```
if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToSettings();
} else {
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
}
```

I can open the native device configuration to mark the geolocation. but I do not know how to do it when the user turns on the geolocation, it simply executes that code but does not get an answer from that. I would like (if possible) to know if the user turned on the geolocation or not.

how can I do it?

I am using `ionic1`, although I suppose that the operation for this solution would apply to any version. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not get callback or response when user turn on/off location from device setting because there is no such way to communicate with Native settings.

But there is a workaround for this. Use [isLocationEnabled()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#islocationenabled) of [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin).

Below is complete working code:

```
  $scope.$on("$ionicView.enter", function() {
        cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(function(enabled) {
          console.log("Location setting is " + (enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));

          if (!enabled) {
            var templateMsg = "Location is not enabled!\nDo you want to enable location service?"
            var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
              title: '<b>Location Service</b>',
              template: '<input alert-enter-key style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;">' + templateMsg.replace(/\n/g, '<br>'),
              okText: "Enable",
              okType: 'ok-button',
              cancelText: "Not now",
              cancelType: 'cancel-button'
            });

            confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
              if (res) {
                if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
                  if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.settings) {
                    window.cordova.plugins.settings.open("settings", function() {
                        console.log('settings opened');
                      },
                      function() {
                        console.log('failed to open settings');
                      }
                    );
                  } else {
                    console.log('openNativeSettingsTest is not active!');
                  }
                } else {
                  cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
                }                  }
            });
          }
        }, function(error) {
          console.error("The following error occurred: " + error);
        });
      });
```

**Note:** To open location setting (**Settings > Privacy > Location Services**) on iOS there is [plugin](https://github.com/guyromb/Cordova-open-native-settings) but There is change/ in iOS 11 platform due to which **you can not** open **Settings > Privacy > Location Services**.

Comment: thank you very much, this works well in android but in ios it does not take me directly to turn on the geolocation, something that can be done for this ?. By the way, am I using  instead of  $scope.$on("$ionicView.enter"  => addEventListener ("resume") is the same?

Comment: @yavg I have updated my answer to open location settings in iOS. Have a look!

Comment: I'm trying virtual machines iphone7 and iphone 8 and I have to use "cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();"

Comment: I'm not sure, but it always goes by the else 'openNativeSettingsTest is not active!'

Comment: `cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();` **does not support iOS**. That is why I added `window.cordova.plugins.settings.open("locations"` if device is iOS. Use what I have added above. It will work 100%.

Comment: thanks for your help!. Sorry, I was wrong, I meant that I put cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToSettings (); I do not know what I'm doing wrong but in your code I'm not getting into (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.settings) but I rehearsed slightly. In my country it is late and I must sleep, but as soon as I can I will try again. thank you very much

Comment: at this precise moment I will prove it. but for some reason you never get into if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.settings) {

Comment: @yavg did you install this ( https://github.com/guyromb/Cordova-open-native-settings ) plugin? You need to install this plugin to run this code.

Comment: with that plugin can I have a promise of when I turn on or off the gps?...

Comment: instead of `window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.settings` just try with `cordova.plugins.settings`

Comment: NO, there is no promise or callback for this. I have already answered this. Please check my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173030/discussion-between-yavg-and-vicjordan).